# Angular generated html not get rendered as expected

Tags: html, angularjs, pdf, markup, jspdf

When I pass the angular generated html to the jspdf, in that case angular classes like ng-hide not affect the generated pdf.
So generated pdf contains the elements that are under the ng-hide class.

Please go through the JS bin attached,
http://jsbin.com/lemewu/edit?html,js,output

I am using following cdnjs
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.2.61/jspdf.debug.js

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. You are using ng-hide wrong. There is difference between using ng-hide and ng-if. Please go through that.
[working link](http://jsbin.com/wehoroditi/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Thanks for quick reply Pradeepb,
But I am using third party library which generate the html that need to rendered. So can't modify the ng-hide tag. Can we have any other way to do so.

Comment: Problem is "ng-hide" shows or hides the given HTML element. It wont remove the elements from HTML markup. Thats the reason when generating PDF, its still visible.

Comment: Thanks again Pradeepb. My goal is to get the pdf of rendered element only. And currently by passing angular contain html to jspdf not work for me. To solve this I uses the html2canvas(To generate image) and jspdf(generate the pdf from image) combination. But it cuts the element while pagination. So do you have any solution which completes my goal.

Comment: Sorry Roshan. I have no idea regarding this.